# Permutation of values on numpy array/matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a code that speed up a creation of permutation matrix.
i.e., I want to create a matrix of n columns, where each column value iterates over m values, creating a n^m combinations on each row.
On the example below, there are 2 methods to create the matrix, in this case n=7 and m=5 that creates a matrix similar to:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 4
1 1 1 1 1 1 5
1 1 1 1 1 2 1
...
5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

The order of the rows doesn't matter, only that all combinations are created.
I have written the following 2 methods to create the arrays, but the metod1 is very slow (although very verbose and clear to understand) and method2 is faster using numpy functions. But I still need to find a faster methodology to create the matrix.

```
import numpy as np

############################################
def permArray_meth1():

    allArray = np.zeros((1,7))

    for a1  in range(1,6):
        for a2  in range(1,6):
            for a3  in range(1,6):
                for a4  in range(1,6):
                    for a5  in range(1,6):
                        for a6  in range(1,6):
                            for a7  in range(1,6):

                                allArray = np.append(allArray, np.array([a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7]).reshape(1,7), axis=0)

    allArray = np.delete(allArray, 0, 0)
    return allArray

############################################
def permArray_meth2():

    ##### Create permutation matrix #####
    a = np.arange(np.power(5,7)).reshape(5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
    allArray = [(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) for a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7 in np.ndindex(a.shape)]

    ##### Convert list to array #####
    allArray = np.asarray(allArray)+1
    return allArray


############################################
if __name__ == "__main__":

    allArray = permArray_meth1()    #  (50sec)
    print 'allArray1', np.shape(allArray)

    allArray = permArray_meth2()    #  (1sec)
    print 'allArray2', np.shape(allArray)
```

I know that the speed is dependent also on the used CPU hardware, but I'm looking for a relatively faster code thatn the shown above.

Is there any other method/code?

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with the matrix? Are you applying functions on the whole matrix or just line by line?

Comment: @plonser, it's to apply functions only line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by creating an `(n, m, m, ..., m)` array of indices for *column 1, column 2, ..., column n* using [`np.indices()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html), then reshaping the output into an `(n ** m, n)` array:

```
import numpy as np

def permgrid(m, n):
    inds = np.indices((m,) * n)
    return inds.reshape(n, -1).T
```

For example:

```
print(permgrid(2, 3))

# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 0 1]
#  [0 1 0]
#  [0 1 1]
#  [1 0 0]
#  [1 0 1]
#  [1 1 0]
#  [1 1 1]]
```